# How to iterate over a map of set (std::map<std::set< char>, int >) in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

For a particular set as key I want to increment how many times the set occurs:

```
      key      value
```

ex : [a , b , c ] =3 times

```
 [a , i ] = 2 times
```

and so on.

how can i iterate over it?
So far i written this ..

```
map<set<char> , int > mp;

for(auto const& elem : mp) {
    for(set<char> :: iterator it = elem->first.begin(); it !=elem->first.end();++it)
        cout << *it << ", ";
    cout<<mp[elem]<<" ";
cout<<"\n";
}
```

but it shows error.Help!

Comment: `for (const auto& [key, value] : mp) { /* ... */ }` (note: C++17)

Comment: @JesperJuhl can u write full code for printing ...please

Comment: No. This is not a free code-writing service. You got a hint, now try some things yourself.

Comment: for(const auto& [key,value] : mp) {
       for(set<char> :: iterator it = key.begin(); it !=key.end();++it)
          cout << *it << ", ";
      cout<<value<<" ";
   cout<<"\n";
} it shows error

Answer (score 1):

You only have `const` access to the key of a map, yet you are trying to use a non-`const` set iterator. That can't work.

The fixed version of your code is:

```
for(auto const& elem : mp) {
    for(set<char>::const_iterator it = elem.first.begin(); it !=elem.first.end();++it)
        cout << *it << ", ";
    cout<<mp[elem]<<" ";
    cout<<"\n";
}
```

Or:

```
for (const auto& elem : mp) {
    for (auto it = elem.first.begin(); it != elem.first.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << ", ";

    std::cout << elem.second << '\n';
}
```

Or the readable alternative:

```
for (const auto& [key,value] : mp)
{
    for (const auto& el : key)
    {
        std::cout << el << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << value << '\n';
}
```

Comment: it still shows error says that  base operand of -> has non pointer type

Comment: @ALLONE Whoops, fixed. The range-for dereferences the iterator for us, giving us just the underlying (key,value) pair.

Comment: Now its right thank youuuuu very very much brother :)

Comment: for(auto const& elem : mapp){
          for(auto const& ele : mapp){
              //do something
    }
}                I want to iterate inside loop from just next element of outside loop how can i do.@Lightness Races IN orbit

Comment: Please ask new questions as new questions, providing all necessary detail and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
for (const auto &map_elem : mp)
{
    for (const auto &set_elem : map_elem.first)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PFK947lwaGlNpK2N)